# Make multiple Java streams assign values more compact

Tags: java, java-stream, method-reference

I have similar lines of code

```
batchPrice1 = items.stream()
                   .map(CommodityItem::getTotalPrice1)
                   .reduce(ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
batchPrice2 = items.stream()
                   .map(CommodityItem::getTotalPrice2)
                   .reduce(ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
batchPrice3 = items.stream()
                   .map(CommodityItem::getTotalPrice3)
                   .reduce(ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Can I make it more compact and less repetetive?

I want a single stream that do the job

Comment: You can make it less repetitive, but it will be much less compact.  You have the shortest code that will do the job already; trying to do it with a single stream will make it _much_ more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest extracting it to method like:

```
batchPrice1 = sum(CommodityItem::getTotalPrice1);
batchPrice2 = sum(CommodityItem::getTotalPrice2);
batchPrice3 = sum(CommodityItem::getTotalPrice3);

private BigDecimal sum(Function<CommidityItem, BigDecimal> mapper){
  return items.stream()
                   .map(mapper)
                   .reduce(ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

Or if you want just one iteration, it can be achieved by

```
YouNameIt accumulator = new YouNameIt();
items.forEach(item-> accumulator.accumulate(item));

class YouNameIt{
    BigDecimal batchPrice1;//getters
    BigDecimal batchPrice2;
    BigDecimal batchPrice3;

    void accumulate(CommodityItem item){
        batchPrice1 += item.getTotalPrice1();
        batchPrice2+= item.getTotalPrice2();
        batchPrice3+= item.getTotalPrice2();
    }
}
```